# Javascript source format very strange

Tags: javascript

Please see [this](http://www.diffchecker.com/dfjrid97)

the "original text" on the left work perfect, the "changed text" on the right give me error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }  MapModule.js:34
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'initialize' of undefined localhost/:103
>   (anonymous function) localhost/:103

I can not understand what the difference is.

if you are wondering how I have modified the file, it is simple, I just used from Aptana 3 source->format...

Comment: The code is the same except whitespace, are you sure that your compiler isn't inserting a `;` delimiter where you're not expecting one in your new white-space configuration? Otherwise the problem is elsewhere (clear cache, etc, check everything is defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement expects that value that you want to return to be in the same row. So this:

```
return {
   a:1
};
```

will work fine, while this:

```
return
{
    a:1
};
```

will return `undefined` because there is nothing behind `return`. What's left behind is this statement:

```
{
    a:1
};
```

This is actual a valid statement that should not produce any errors. As Spoike and Bergi already mentioned, you are receiving a syntax error because you had a trailing comma behind `a:1` which suggests, that there should be another property following the property `a`, which isn't there.

Btw. here is a link to a video of Doug Crockford explaining this very case and also why `{a:1};` is a valid statement: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook#t=30m38s

Comment: That's why I like SO... I never stop learning new stuff everyday! Thanks!

Comment: Nope. It is because automatic semicolon insertion (ASI), not because the javascript interpreter is confused. It is an actual rule that inserts a semicolon after the return statement, leading the function to return `undefined`.

Comment: @Spoike That's correct. But the statement after the return statement `{a:1};` is interpreted by some interpreters as a valid statement so that it won't result in a syntax error. OPs interpreter obviously throws an error but when I run it in Chrome, the function just silently returns `undefined` without any notification that something is wrong.

Comment: It's not the statement that confuses the javascript engine, it's the trailing comma in the "object literal"

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you're right. Good catch to you and to Spoike. Didn't notice the trailing comma.

Answer (score 2):

You've broken the `return` statement.  You can't start an object literal on the next line after a `return` statement, because the parser will get confused. You have to leave the `{` on the same line as `return`, in other words.

The issue involves the problematic and controversial JavaScript "semicolon insertion" rules.

The original code also includes a stray comma at the end of the object literal. That should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

This is because JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI) that will insert a semicolon after certain statements if you're ending them with line breaks. You can read about it in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).

In your case the code has a line break at the return statement that will have a semicolon inserted. This means that:

```
return 
{
   initialize: initialize,
};
```

.. will become the following:

```
return;
{
   initialize: initialize,
};
// will now always return undefined
```

---

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } MapModule.js:34

This error is because you have a trailing comma inside the object literal:

```
return {
    initialize: initialize, // <-- whoops
}
```

This is actually legal in most JS engines... except IE's. Surprisingly this is the one thing IE does according to spec. :-) To fix this, avoid trailing commas:

```
return {
    initialize: initialize // FIXED
}
```

Hope this clears some things up.

Comment: Sorry but I'm pretty sure that the `ìf` statement doesn't end prematurely because of ASI. It actually works just fine that way.

Comment: @basilikum: You're correct, sorry about that confusion. Removed that part of the question. :-)

Comment: Please remove the second part of your answer, it's wrong. If statements do allow line terminators between `)` and the following block, so ASI will not jump in. It's different for returns statements only because they require no line terminator to be between `return` and the optional expression. Check [the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9)!

Comment: @Bergi: It's been removed before your comment.